# Firebase how to limit results from server side?

Tags: firebase

I know firebase can limit the results from the client side, but the client side can be changed easily.

Let's say that I have a list of cities.
The user can search any city.
The maximum results will be 10.

From my knowledge If the client will change the client side code he can disable this limitTo and he can get all the city list.
 There is a way to limit the results from server side of firebase so if the user will want to get all the city list he will get only 10?

Answer (score 0):

Which platform?

Check the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/retrieve-data).

This is a node.js example taken from the documentation.

```
var ref = db.ref("dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("weight").limitToLast(2).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

Comment: I am using fire base in my iOS, so it's in client side